# Permalink for specific page name

Tags: permalinks, page-template, htaccess

I create a new page with post name is 'my-page'. I also have 2 custom query strings. So, the URL will be like:

http://domain.com/my-page/?qst1=aaa&qst2=bbb

I want the URL like:

http://domain.com/aaa/bbb

How I can do it? How I can tell WP it is a valid URL, because WP will point to 404 page (aaa page not found).

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess you should be able to do something like what is shown by Chris Coyier on CSS Tricks.

Link to example by Chris Coyier: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/subdirectories-redirect-query-string/

Since you don't have .php in your URL, WordPress has most likely already created RewriteEngine rules for you to not need .php. But the result should still work fine.

**EDIT:**

Another example of this is shown with pretty much the same exact scenario as you.
It's on Apache's Wiki website: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString
The example shown to do this in your .htaccess is something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/path /path/%1/%2?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add add_rewrite_rule function in your website. For your case you can try this following code

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );
function wpse12065_init() { 
add_rewrite_rule(
    'my-page(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
    'index.php?pagename=my-page&qst1=$matches[2]&qst2=$matches[4]',
     'top'      
);
```

Then save your permalink.

In my-page Page ( you need to create custom page template ) you can catch that query vars with this code

```
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['qst1']) && !empty($wp_query->query_vars['qst1']) ) {
$qst1 = $wp_query->query_vars['qst1'];
}
else {
//do something else 
}
//do the same step for qst2
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use permalink setting Custom Structure /%category%/%postname%/.

or You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/ plugin.